# SQL Join can't figure it out

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have a table called `website` that contains some data about websites. The columns of this table are: id, website, quick_url, user_id, status, etc.

Each website that is in the table was added by a user, which is is saved in the user_id column.

I have another table called `blocks` that has only 3 columns: `id, user_id, website_id`.

I want to get all the websites from the `website` table, that were not added by a given user_id, but also, only the websites that were not blocked by the given user_id. So, websites that were not added by a given user or blocked by him.

Here is what I've tried:

```
SELECT * FROM website LEFT OUTER JOIN blocks ON tbl_website.userid = blocks.user_id WHERE website.user_id = blocks.user_id AND blocks.user_id = NULL AND website,user_id != '177' LIMIT 500;
```

It doesn't give me the wanted results ...

First, I've tried to do it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_website WHERE id<>(SELECT website_id from tbl_website_blocks WHERE user_id = '177')
```

which makes much more sense for me than my previous query, but I get this error: **Subquery returns more than 1 row**

I guess you can't have a "loop in loop" in an SQL query.

I'm aware that I could do two queries, and filter the results, but I would like to do it as much as possible from the SQL language, so that I don't "overload" the server.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second query rewrite the condition on

```
WHERE id not in (SELECT website_id from.....)
```

with `<>` you can compare it with just one value but your select returns list of values, so you can use `not in` to get results that are different then the selected list of IDs

Comment: Actualy i was faster :P Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of '<>', try 'Not In'

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_website 
WHERE id Not In (SELECT website_id from tbl_website_blocks WHERE user_id = '177')
```

I should also add this query is not a Join.